# UPDATE columns using JSON data

Tags: postgresql-11

I have found two solutions that update columns based on JSON data. The first solution is based on CTE:

```
WITH list AS (
SELECT * FROM json_populate_record
(null::tsk,'{"tsk_id":"2","tsk_subject":"test","tsk_desc":"abc"}'))
UPDATE tsk
SET (tsk_subject,tsk_desc) = (SELECT tsk_subject,tsk_desc FROM list) WHERE tsk_id=1;
```

The other solution that works, but I cannot find a way to update ONE record only.

```
UPDATE tsk
SET (tsk_subject, tsk_desc) = (j.tsk_subject, j.tsk_desc)
FROM json_populate_record ( null::tsk,
   '{"tsk_id":"3","tsk_subject":"test2","tsk_desc":"abc2"}'::json
) j ;
```

My question is if there are other solutions for updating one record using JSON data? Or is this a good way to do this?

dbfiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eaQG8H4yqY9hnQBZjzJgz/81

Comment: Perhaps you need a `WHERE` in the second version? Unclear what you are trying to achieve, where are you getting the new data from?

Comment: @charlieface If I put WHERE after j in the second query, I get an error. The data is submitted from a HTML form. Both when inserting and updating. I am trying to achieve CRUD using AJAX from a web app. CREATE and READ is finished, but now I am searching for ways to UPDATE. The queries above work, but I wonder if there are even better/safer ways to UPDATE a record from JSON

Comment: `WHERE tsk.tsk_id=1;` seems to work fine for me https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=04a799268a9d3eb0f8ebe61b04694590 although it's unclear why you are using JSON at all in this instance (was it just an example of where you have existing JSON that you want to use?)